# Spark Scala DataFrame repartition by a column error

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

> I have a DS joined in Spark. I am using scala. I want to partition the DS on a column "date". I am using the following syntax. The code does not throw Compile Error:

```
joined.repartition(joined.col("date")).show()
```

> The Scala repartition function is defined as follows:

```
def repartition(partitionExprs : org.apache.spark.sql.Column*) : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T] = { /* compiled code */ }
```

> However when I execute the code in Spark, I get the following error in Run time. What am I doing wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.wrapRefArray([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/immutable/ArraySeq;
            at example.Stocks$.main(Stocks.scala:38)
            at example.Stocks.main(Stocks.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: why don't you just use `col("date")`?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably compiling to the wrong version of Scala (and probably Spark as well). You can verify your running version with `spark-submit --version`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can isolate then, may be try to run the same on spark-shell. I usually use it for troubleshooting the spark jobs.